# How to un-AssignCrt(Output)?

Tags: delphi, pascal, crt, turbo-pascal

In TurboPascal program i took an advantage of DOS *processed output* and use Tab *control character* to form columns in the output:

```
const Tab = #09;
...
Writeln(X, Tab, F(X));
```

However, when i tried to add a `pause`-like functionality via `ReadKey` call and used `Crt` module, *processed output* broke, and the statement illustrated above began writing generic Tab glyph instead forming columns at the tab stops.

As i figured out, source of this phenomenon is `AssignCrt(Output)` call at the module initialization, which redefines means how `Writeln` works - it no longer uses DOS for output, but either video BIOS or direct video memory access (depending on `DirectVideo` value) instead.

How do i **reverse** whatever `AssignCrt` does? As far as i know from the documentation, there `Crt` module provides no means to restore normal output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Crt` textfile driver does not support the `tab` character in `turbo-pascal`.
To revert back the standard `dos` driver, do as follows:

> Assign(Output,'');  // Restores standard dos output

You can later reinstate the Crt driver by:

> AssignCrt(Output);